# Polynomial ring as a module over ring of invariants

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, invariant-theory, computational-algebra, general-linear-group

Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a field of characteristic 0 and $S=\mathbf{k}[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ be a polynomial algebra over $\mathbf{k}$. Let $G\subset GL_n(\mathbf{k})$ act linearly on $S$ and $R = S^G$ be the ring of invariants.

We know that $R$ is f.g. $\mathbf{k}$-algebra, say $R=\mathbf{k}[f_1,\ldots, f_r]$.

Using results from Smith's book, we know that $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ is a regular sequence if and only if $S$ is a free $R$-module, of rank $|G|$. Some related questions are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1004341/114534) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1747404/114534).

My question is:
What can we say about $S$ as an $R$-module otherwise? i.e. if $f_i$'s *do not* form a regular sequence?

1. Is $S$ finitely generated?
2. If yes, is there any way to **compute** generators of $S$ as $R$-module?
3. Any bound on the number of generators?
4. Any known results on this module structure? -- may be in spacial cases?

From computational point of view, is there any CAS that can do this computation?

Please correct me if I am wrong:
Possible examples of such groups I can think of are the ones which generate $A,D,E$ singularities.